# GTM Trigger Custom Tag after Ajax Complete

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to trigger GTM tag after jQuery ajaxComplete event.

### Tag 1

It should be fired on **Page View** and every time on **ajaxComplete**:

```
console.log('cleanup')
```

Page View trigger is clear and simple.

### Tag 2

As for ajax I'm setting up additional tag to detect ajaxComplete:

```
  var gtm = google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}];
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    try {
      gtm.onHtmlSuccess({{HTML ID}});      
      console.log('success');
    } catch(e) {
      gtm.onHtmlFailure({{HTML ID}});
      console.log('failure')
    }
  });
```

It trigger onHtmlSuccess() on ajaxComplete.
Cleanup tag is set to **Tag 1** to trigger tag sequence.

This tag combo should work like this:

1. On page load **Tag 1** fires (this par it OK)
2. On ajaxComplete **Tag 2** fires onHtmlSuccess()
3. After onHtmlSuccess() **Tag 1** should be fired again (due to tag sequence)

Not clear why items 2 and 3 are not working as I expect.
Any advice?

Comment: are you trying to fire some customer events in GTM? then you probably should check https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/custom-event-listeners-gtm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it this way:

### Step 1

Create the following Custom HTML tag:

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'ajaxStop'
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

It adds ajaxStop value to dataLayer event key right on jQuery ajaxStop event.

### Step 2

Next add Custom Event tag with event name value set to ajaxStop: http://prntscr.com/i4swhv

### Step 3

Create the following Custom HTML tag:

```
<script>
  var gtm = google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}];
  try {
    gtm.onHtmlSuccess({{HTML ID}});
  } catch(e) {
    gtm.onHtmlFailure({{HTML ID}});
  }
</script>
```

Add any other Custom HTML tag as a Cleanup tag to this one.

It did exactly what I needed.